# Duplicate key error when importing sql file with BEFORE INSERT trigger

Tags: mysql

in my `.sql` file there is a lines like so:

```
SET @OLDTMP_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `thasil2bi` BEFORE INSERT ON `t_hasil2` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
set new.c_kode=concat(new.c_kodejudul,new.c_bulan,new.c_tahun);
END//
DELIMITER ;
SET SQL_MODE=@OLDTMP_SQL_MODE;
```

everytime i try to import this `.sql` file there is error saying

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'A1.1-1-2015' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

when i look into the file and search for combination of `c_kodejudul = 'A1.1'` and `c_bulan=1` and `c_tahun=2015`. there is only one row that having these combination, nothing more. what happen with my sql file?

Comment: What about searching for an existing `c_kode` value of `'A1.1-1-2015'`. If this is a DB dump, it may have pre-populated primary key values

Comment: Also, where are the hyphens coming from? If your record is `c_kodejudul = 'A1.1'`, `c_bulan=1` and `c_tahun=2015`, the result of the above `concat` would be `'A1.112015'`

Comment: already did that, nothing more.

Comment: yes Phil the result is `'A1.112015'` and there is only one search result

Comment: Sounds like you're looking in the wrong place then. The duplicate key is `'A1.1-1-2015'`, not `'A1.112015'`

Comment: before i search for `A1.112015` i searched `A1.1-1-2015` no result tough

Comment: Yeah, doesn't sound like that exact value is in your SQL file however the trigger you've posted in your question should not generate the value in the error message unless those columns actually contain values like `'A1.1-'`, `'-2015'`, etc. Like I said, you're looking in the wrong place. Are there any instances of `CONCAT_WS`?

Comment: here is first line of the sql
`('A1', 'A1.1', 'BATUBARA', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-07', 1, '2015', 2, 'Bandung', 'Hotel Kagum Group Bandung (Golden Flower, Banana Inn, Amaroossa, Serela, Gino Feruci), Grand Setiabudi, De Java', 3, '6.500.000', '6.250.000', '5.950.000', 0, NULL, 'public', 'A1.112015')`

could it be because of that TRIGGER recreating another row that have simillar c_kode?

Comment: The trigger doesn't create a new row, it just changes the `c_kode` value of the row being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Please search 'A1.1-1-2015' in your sql file

1. if it is found twice, delete SQL command which inserts duplicate from SQL file.
2. If it is found once, you might have incomplete sql execution sometimes before,so go to the database delete all tables and re execute sql file

Comment: no result for that string. if i permitted to copy/paste the script then i would do  it, so that you could see the file directly